# Use custom user authentication in FastApi AWS environment

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, fastapi

this is just about best practice. I am currently developing an API with Python-Framework FastApi. I am deploying this via AWS Lambda, API Gateway and use DynamoDB as storage. After implementing some CRUD-Operations, I now want to add Authentication and Authorization. Idea is that users can login with username (or email) and password to get a bearer token.

Since I am not very much into Cognito, I thought about adding the Auth-functionality within the FastApi code (create registration and login endpoints i.e. with fastapi-users library). From best practice view, is that OK? Or are there significant reasons to use Cognito and API-Gateway Authorizers for that?

Comment: If you're already using other AWS services, then Cognito is probably what you'll want to go with. That said, you can also use other managed auth providers, like Auth0, if you don't want to use Cognito.

In general try to avoid rolling your own authentication and authorisation system unless it's an absolute requirement. If this is the case, you can use FastAPI's Depends() class to implement both token based authentication, and role-based authorisation (for example: https://learnings.desipenguin.com/post/rolechecker-with-fastapi/)